# Get Entity composed of child entities in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design

I have some 'complex' entities formed by other entities. For Example the 'Order' Entity:

- Order
- OrderDetail (child)
- OrderDetailsDiscount (child of the child)
- OrderPayment
- OrderState

The code for the Order class:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(OrderMetadata))]
public partial class Order
{
    public OrderPaymentStatus PaymentStatus {
        get { return Paid ? OrderPaymentStatus.Paid : OrderPaymentStatus.Pending; }
    }

    public bool Paid {
        get {
            return TotalPaid >= Total;
        }
    }

    public decimal TotalPaid {
        get {
            return OrderPayments.Sum(p => p.Amount);
        }
    }

    public decimal TotalRefund {
        get {
            return OrderRefunds.Sum(p => p.Amount);
        }
    }

    public decimal TotalDebt {
        get {
            return Total - TotalPaid + TotalRefund;
        }
    }

    public decimal TotalDiscounts {
        get {
            return ((SubTotal * DiscountPercentage) / 100) + DiscountAbsolute;
        }
    }

    public decimal TotalSurcharges {
        get {
            return ((SubTotal * SurchargePercentage) / 100);
        }
    }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public decimal Total {
        get {
            return SubTotal - TotalDiscounts + TotalSurcharges;
        }
    }

    public decimal TotalTax {
        get {
            return (TaxEnabled) ? OrderDetails.Sum(t => t.Taxes): 0;
        }
    }

    public decimal SubTotal {
        get {
            return OrderDetails.Sum(o => o.Total) + TotalTax;
        }
    }

    public decimal DiscountOffers {
        get {
            return OrderDetails.Sum(o => o.DiscountOffers);
        }
    }

    public bool HasOffers {
        get { 
            return DiscountOffers > 0; 
        }
    }

    public decimal SurchargePercentage {
        get {
            return OrderSurcharges.Sum(o => o.ChargePercentage);
        }
    }

    public decimal DiscountPercentage {
        get {
            return OrderDiscounts.Where(o => o.Type == (int)DiscountType.Percentage).Sum(o => o.Value);
        }
    }

    public decimal DiscountAbsolute
    {
        get
        {
            return OrderDiscounts.Where(o => o.Type == (int)DiscountType.Absolute).Sum(o => o.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

I dinamically calculate the order total so I allways need OrderDetail.* loaded from start to avoid multiple queries to the DB when presentig a list of 1000 orders for example so I have implemented this method in my generic repository :

```
    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = Fetch();

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        return query;
    }
```

And I call it form my code like this :

```
    private IEnumerable<Order> GetAllOrders()
    {
        return unitOfWork.OrderRepository.GetAllIncluding(
            o => o.OrderDiscounts,
            o => o.OrderPayments,
            o => o.OrderSurcharges,
            o => o.OrderStates,
            o => o.OrderRefunds,
            o => o.OrderDetails,
            o => o.OrderDetails.Select(d => d.OrderDetailDiscounts),
            o => o.OrderDetails.Select(d => d.OrderDetailOffers),
            o => o.User,
            o => o.Employee,
            o => o.Store,
            o => o.TerminalSession);
    }
```

Ok .. It works.. the problem is when I have to query other complex objects with this one, I have the User Entity wich is composed of other child entities for example:

- User
- UserPoint
- UserState
- ...

Is there any way to instruct EF to load a group of entities as a whole so I can query using Orders and Users fully loaded to aviod hitting the db when requesting lots of records (I don't want to disable lazy loading)

Comment: Can't you just add: `o => o.User.GetAllIncluding(o => u.UserPoint, u => u.UserState,...)`?

Comment: Yes, te problem is a query involving User.* and Order.* for example : un paid orders from active users with less that 100 points

Comment: To me it looks like you should not try to compose the one size fits all queries. Do you ever need _all_ these includes for one use case? I think (but I may be wrong) you should use more tailor-made queries with (far) less includes and maybe some joins sometimes. If you _really_ want you can preload anything. It may require a query or two but EF will kindly fixup relationships. But again, I think you query to much data.

Comment: I'm using automapper, the Order entity is mapped to OrderDTO so automapper access the properties of the Order entity to map properties on OrderDTO generating high amounts of queries to the DB

Answer (score 0):

```
context.Entity.Include("ChildEntity");
```

or

```
context.Entity.Include( x => x.ChildEntity);
```

if you need more nested entities

```
context.Entity.Include( x => x.ChildEntity.Select( c => c.ChildChildEntity ));
```

keep in mind that the lambda expression lives on `System.Data.Entity` namespace.

Remember that in general too many joins is worse than multiple db calls.